# Cannot start Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT)

Tags: java, monitoring

I've downloaded MAT from this [link](https://www.eclipse.org/mat/downloads.php) and simply extract the zip file to use. Then, when I executed the `MemoryAnalyzer.exe`, I got this errror

[image]

My `%JAVA_HOME%` is already `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251`.

Could you guys help me please?

Comment: It seems its loading different JDk  not `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251` , you can set the system environment variable(Control Panel -> Enviornment variable->Edit Path varaible) for the java in Path attribute `%JAVA_HOME%/bin`

Comment: Also note that MAT may require 64-bit JDK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you set your `JAVA_HOME` correctly and it still doesn't work, you can try add below line to the `MemoryAnalyzer.ini`

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin
```

But remeber to add before `-vmargs` option.

You can also try to add `jvm.dll` path directly:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\server\jvm.dll
```

Also check this out: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Windows_Example

Comment: It must be 2 lines. The first line for "-vm", the second line for the path.

Answer (score 1):

If using MacOS, make sure you have JVM 11 or above installed and add the following line to `MemoryAnalyzer.ini` by replacing the JAVA_HOME variable.

```
-vm
$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And make sure this flag is before `-vmargs`